# Vanilla JS: Where to place a re-render in a dynamically generated component that are dynamically added to the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom

Using Vanilla JS I'm trying to add a copy and delete option to my array of, let's them them "events." I get why what I'm trying isn't working, but not sure how to go forward placing the re-render call without over-adding/deleting from the array.

```
renderEvents = () => {
 document.getElementById('my-events').innerHTML = events.map((ev, i) => {
  document.getElementById('my-events').addEventListener('click', (e) => {

   if (e.target && e.target.matches(`img#copy-icon-${i}`) {
    events.push(events.find((eve) => eve.name === ev.name));
    //Adds to the array but isn't rendering, tried call renderEvents() recursively here but copied multiple elements to the array instead of the single desired element. Adding a break doesn't work due to this being invoked by another function
   }

   if (e.target && e.target.matches(`img#delete-icon-${i}`) {
    events.splice(events.findIndex((eve) => eve.name === ev.name), 1);
   //Works without a re-render, tried calling renderEvents() recursively here but was splicing 2 elements at the index
   }

  return( HTML for the render pattern, includes #copy-icon-${i} and #delete-icon-${i})
 });
)};
```

#my-events is an empty div, just in case.

Comment: fix this: document.getElementById('my-events')  // end the single quote correctly

Comment: Fixed, not the question being asked though.